# How to host a dockerized Laravel website on Heroku?

Tags: laravel, heroku

I have a dockerized Laravel application that consists of MySQL database and Redis.
I want to deploy and test it on the internet.
is there any way to have an environment such as Heroku to deploy it?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker there's also many other solutions (though most probably wont be free)

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks yes i saw this documentation. but it was not so useful. i will review them again